# create a class and calling its methods

Tags: matlab

I have set a path in my pathdef (C:\MyFolder\Classes) where I have the BankAccount and AccountManager class examples from MATLAB, I have just added Test to the end of each name for testing purposes.

So when in a different path I can run the line below and it works fine. I step through and see it open the BankAccountTest file.

```
 mb = BankAccountTest(12345, 1000);
```

Now I have tried adding a new class say called MyFuncs to the same directory as the classes above.

```
classdef MyFuncs
 methods(Static)      
    function [mynum] = test_func(intOne, intTwo)
       mynum = intOne * intTwo; 
    end
 end
end
```

When I try the line below

```
 nm = MyFuncs.test_func(5, 6);
```

I get the error message,

```
Undefined variable "MyFuncs" or class "MyFuncs.test_func".
```

Why can it not 'see' this class but it can see the others?

**Answer**

Closing my Matlab and and re-opening it seems to have done the trick

Comment: If there is an existing (or has recently been) an instance (variable) of a previous version of `MyFuncs` it will need to be cleared as MATLAB will be using the currently loaded classdef, `clear classes` can help here (WARNING: this will also clear the workspace, globals etc...). Less likely but secondly it could be a problem with MATLAB not seeing the new classdef yet if it has recently been added from outside the MATLAB enviroment, for this try `rehash path`

Comment: In response to the edit... closing and re-opening will clear everything and rehash the path